# What is the difference between "enableImplicitConversion" and "transform" in NestJS

Tags: javascript, nestjs, class-validator, class-transformer

I'm wonder what a difference between

```
transform: true
```

And

```
 transformOptions: {
      enableImplicitConversion: true,
    }
```

From documentation I don't quite understand which I must to use for what cases.

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation
https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer

Answer (score 0):

`transform` means that the `ValidationPipe` will return the new class instance at the end of the pipe call. This has no effect on the validations ran, as `plainToClass` will be called regardless so that `validate` can run against the class.

`enableImplicitConversion` will tell `class-transformer` that if it sees a primitive that is currently a string (like a boolean or a number) to assume it should be the primitive type instead and transform it, even though `@Type(() => Number)` or `@Type(() => Boolean)` isn't used.

Comment: The documentation (https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation) shows an example with string -> int inside controller when `transform: true`

> With the auto-transformation option enabled, the ValidationPipe will also perform conversion of primitive types

So in this case both of this parameters works in same mode but in case of "transform" it returns class instance at the end?

Comment: The `implicitiConversion` is useful for things like `@Query()` and `@Param()` which will always come in as strings. With request bodies, json and urlencoded usually do a good job with parsing these out to their primitives, so keep that in mind as well

Comment: Can we claim that `transform` is only used to convert DTO (objects) when `enableImplicitConversion` is used even for `@Query` , `@Param` type conversion  ?

Comment: Not quite. Like I said, `transform: true` tells the pipe to return the auto transformed value. If it is not set, the original incoming value will be used

Comment: I still do not understand the main answer, how it differs from each other and when to use it if in the end they do plus or minus the same thing. 
Might need to do some research. 
Thanks for your answers